# record https traffic for proxy based web applications in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a web application which is hosted to a proxy server.I need to record some scripts of this web application using Jmeter. 
When i set browser proxy to Jmeter localhost:8888 i am unable to access my web application which is hosted on some other proxy server.
I need to set up both proxies at same time in my browser and do recording.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to use the proxy in order to access your application you need to let JMeter know your proxy server details. As per [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) user manual entry:

   > To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with the following parameters:
   >
   > -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
   >
   > -P [proxy server port]
   >
   > -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
   >
   > -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
   >
   > -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]

   ```
   jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password
   ```
2. In order to be able to record HTTPS traffic you will need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser. The relevant file is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the above manual entry for more details and [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) for more details.